# Which countries are these, and who's the missing man?

Tags: pattern, geography

Identify each country in the following list, and then work out what they all have in common.

- A little piece of Europe by a newly discovered island.
- An Arab state with power beyond its size.
- A former colony that waves a rifle proudly.
- A nation wracked by war, which sounds much like its neighbour.
- With 3 official languages, its name betrays its location.

Once you've found them all and their common property, **what is the name of the man I've omitted** from the list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A little piece of Europe by a newly discovered island.

> **Saint Pierre and Miquelon** – is a French *collectivité d'outre mer*, a French overseas territory near Newfoundland.

An Arab state with power beyond its size.

> **Qatar** – is only a small state, but it has the highest per capita income in the world.

A former colony that waves a rifle proudly.

> **Mozambique** – was a Portuguese colony until 1975 and has an AK-47 with bayonet in its flag.

A nation wracked by war, which sounds much like its neighbour.

> **Iraq** – sounds a bit like Iran, its neighbour to the east.

With 3 official languages, its name betrays its location.

> **Equatorial Guinea** – has the official languages French, Spanish and Portuguese and, despite its name, has no territory on the equator. (The southern border of the mainland is at 1°N; the island province Annobón lies completely south of the equator.)

The common property is that ...

> ... they all have a Q in their (English) name.
>
>  Working from the [list of countries with a country code](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1), the last one should be **Martinique**, a French *département d'outre-mer*. That would make the man omitted from the list someone named **Martin**.

Comment: Good job! (Re #3: they do sound almost the same in my accent at least. Would you pronounce the "a" differently in the two names?)

Comment: No, but I think that the pronounced ending letter is distinctive enough. But I'm wrog, too: The q with its descender doesn't look anything like an n. Let's agree on: The have an edit distance of 1. `:)`

Comment: This is *almost* right, but wouldn't it make more sense after swapping round the last two countries you found? You should get an *aha* moment at some point with "newly discovered island" ...

Comment: I had thought about that, but with your gentle nudge I think I've now got my aha moment. I didn't need to go to the [List of nes islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_new_islands) after all. But I thought that "part of Europe" worked better with the DOM Martinique.

Comment: Yep, Martin Ique was the intended final answer. Nicely done!

Comment: _Saint Pierre and Miquelon_ is in North America - at least geographically.  OK, so it is a puzzle

Comment: @chux: It is an overseas territory of France, hence a little piece of Europe. (But I think that description works better for Martinique, because it is an overseas department, which should have an equal status to the départements in metropolitan France.)

Comment: "Its name betrays its location" Equatorial guinea has no land on the equator, just north and south of it.

Comment: @ev3commander: Ah, that's why it betrays its name. I misread that. (But the OED has "equatorial:Of, at, or near the equator", so that would make the name okay, I guess, considereing where the other Guineas are.)

Comment: @randal'thor: _Martin Ique_, is that Latin: Flavia IV Martin Ique (Flavia IV. and Martin I.)?

Answer (score 2):

PARTIAL ANSWER:
No.2

> Saudi Arabia?

No.4:

> Iraq (Sounds like its neighbour Iran)

Comment: #4 is correct, #2 isn't.